# クライアントからSocket.ioに接続しているクライアント一覧を取得

Tags: node.js, socket.io

クライアントからSocket.ioに接続しているクライアント一覧を取得したいと思っています。

```
var http = require("http");
var server = http.createServer(function(req,res) {
    res.write("Hello World!!"); // ・・・　①
    res.end(); // ・・・　②
});

// socketioの準備
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

// クライアント接続時の処理
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log("client connected!!")

    // クライアント切断時の処理
    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        console.log("client disconnected!!")
    });
    // クライアントからの受信を受ける (socket.on)
    socket.on("from_client", function(obj){
        console.log(obj)
    });
});

server.listen(8080);
```

の①②の部分を

```
//接続しているクライアント情報取得    
var clients = io.sockets.clients();
//接続しているクライアント数取得 
var count = clients.length;

if (count !== 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        res.write(clients[i]);
        res.write("</ br>");
        res.end();
    }
}
```

にして、クライアントから`http://<node.jsのサーバドメイン>/`にアクセスすれば一覧が出るようにしたいです。
しかし、この中ではioのインスタンスも作られていないためエラーが生じます。

どのように対処すればいいかご存じの方、ご教示お願いします。

Answer (score -1):

①②の時点はコールバック関数の中なのでioのインスタンスは作られていると思います。
ただこちら(socket.io 1.3.6)で試したところclients関数が無くてエラーが出たので、
io.eio.clientsCountやio.eio.clientsなどでクライアントの情報が取れました。
正しい取り方なのかはわかりませんが…。